# Android Studio nested composite build - plugin com.android.library not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a working composite build in Android Studio, consisting of 
Project A (app)
Project B (lib)

I now want to add another dependency to project B, which will be another library project.
As I understand it, Gradle supports nested composite builds since 4.10.
I have modified the settings.gradle in project B and added:

```
def projectB = '../../ProjectB/projectB'
includeBuild(projectB)
```

When I try to gradle sync Project B, I get the errors:

```
Build file '/Users/xxxx/Documents/source/ProjectB/projectB/build.gradle' line: 1
A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectB'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

Is it event possible to do what I am trying to do? I can't seem to find a good example of nested composite builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use `include` instead of `includeBuild` like this:

```
include("project1", "project2:child", "project3:child1")
```

The `include` method takes project paths as arguments. The project path is assumed to be equal to the relative physical file system path. For example, a path `services:api` is mapped by default to a folder `services/api` (relative from the project root). You only need to specify the leaves of the tree. This means that the inclusion of the path `services:hotels:api` will result in creating 3 projects: `services`, `services:hotels` and `services:hotels:api`.

For more [check this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file)